# Paper based OTP and MAC

Tags: mac, one-time-pad

Consider the following paper based OTP

1. Plaintext has 11 possible symbols 0-10.
2. $C_i = M_i + K_i\ mod\ 11$.
3. $K_i$ comes from a pre-shared key material which is never reused.

How to introduce data integrity/ MAC in it which can be calculated using pen & paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SHA3-224 [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Define a security parameter $\kappa$, and both sides consume
that much $K_i$ keying material.
A paper based OTP will probably choose a smaller parameter
than a TCP-based protocol would choose.

Compute and append the $\kappa$ prefix of the HMAC result
to the message, encoded as base 11 digits.

Transmit the $C_i$ message as above.

Receiver computes HMAC and verifies that the prefix matches.

EDIT

> ...which can be calculated using pen & paper.

Oohhhh. Well *there's* a new wrinkle.

Define a new security parameter $D$, number of check digits to send.

Define a base $B$.
It most naturally would be 11,
but for human convenience we may choose to make it 10.
It is possible that some
[casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines)
procedure would motivate using 9.

Find a running total of the various $M_i$ figures, $\mod B$,
and write the number down beneath each $M_i$.

Append the final $D$ such numbers to the message.

Transmit this augmented message as OP describes.
Notice that each check digit is protected by its own $K_i$.

Receiver performs the same steps to verify.

---

Observation: Mallet has a much better chance for
undetected corruption of one of the final $D$ characters
of the original message under this "scheme-A",
*especially* if he wants to corrupt its final character.

Remedy: In "scheme-B", consume $D$ characters of the $K_i$ keying material
and append those to the original message at the very beginning of the procedure,
so we're transmitting a checksum of characters both
unknown and known to the recipient.

---

Assume that "keying material is cheap",
so for example we are willing to consume 200 characters
of $K_i$ to send a message of length 100.
Could we use that to improve robustness?
Assume that "$D$ is small",
that is, $D < \sqrt{ |M| }$
where $|M|$ is length of message.

Second observation: Humans are fallible.
Sometimes we write down arithmetic mistakes.
Could we rescue parts of a message that Alice accidentally garbled?

Remedy: Starting from the message's end, break out $D$ message chunks.
Most will be of equal size; the first few are likely to be shorter by one.
Compute and transmit per-chunk checksums independently.

At this point I also want to send "more than one" (how many?)
combined checksum digits which summarize the individual transmitted checksums.
Maybe one for the odds, one for the evens?
Or a tree that transmits eight checksums, then four checksums of pairs,
then two checksums, then finally a master checksum?

Leaning on the "fallibility" aspect, maybe spend part of our checksum
budget on computing / transmitting checksums of **reversed**
message characters?